# richTextbox1 to textbox1?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have this text in a rich text box named `richTextBox`:

```
    <notification_counts>
    <unseen>0</unseen>
  </notification_counts>
  <friend_requests_counts>
    <unread>1</unread>
    <unseen>**0**</unseen>
  </friend_requests_counts>
```

I would like to extract the value from the `unseen` tag (0 in this example) and place it in the text box named `textbox1`. How should I go about doing this?

Full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notifications_get_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <messages>
    <unread>0</unread>
    <unseen>0</unseen>
    <most_recent>****</most_recent>
  </messages>
  <pokes>
    <unread>0</unread>
    <most_recent>0</most_recent>
  </pokes>
  <shares>
    <unread>0</unread>
    <most_recent>0</most_recent>
  </shares>
  <notification_counts>
    <unseen>0</unseen>
  </notification_counts>
  <friend_requests_counts>
    <unread>1</unread>
    <unseen>0</unseen>
  </friend_requests_counts>
  <friend_requests list="true">
    <uid>***</uid>
  </friend_requests>
  <group_invites list="true"/>
  <event_invites list="true"/>
</notifications_get_response>
```

Comment: And .... the suspense is killing me....

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: there are tags in richTextBox 1 (<notification>...ecc ecc> at button clic is possibble extracting this tag <unseen> and insert a textbox1 with the value?

Comment: @jolly, is that a Windows Forms `RichTextBox` or a WPF one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rich text box only contains XML markup, you can parse it to extract the value you're interested in. For instance, using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

textBox1.Text = XElement.Parse(richTextBox.Text)
                        .Descendant("friend_requests_counts")
                        .Element("unseen").Value;
```

**EDIT:** Since your XML markup contains [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), you have to take them into account when selecting the elements:

```
XNamespace fb = "http://api.facebook.com/1.0/";
textBox1.Text = XDocument.Parse(richTextBox.Text).Root
                         .Element(fb + "friend_requests_counts")
                         .Element(fb + "unseen").Value;
```

Comment: Interesting, are you sure the XML markup in your rich text box is valid? For instance, the excerpt in your question is not (since there are two root elements). Can you update your question with the full markup, if it's not too big?

Comment: No problem :) This looks like an XML namespace issue. See my updated answer.